# How to get datepicker to be highlighted upon refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker that highlights a selected week. It is using an ajax request. Which is where I am having a problem. When I select a week i.e. 29/08/11 and the page refreshes the highlighted week is no longer highlighted.

**Datepicker.js**

```js
$(function()
{
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var selectCurrentWeek = function()
    {
        window.setTimeout(function () { $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')}, 1000);
    }
    function check(d) {
        if(d.length() == 2) {
            dd = d;
            return dd;
        } else {
            dd = "0" + myDateParts[0];
            return dd;
        }
    }

    var selectedWeek;//remember which week the user selected here

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd'
            var newDate = $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));

            var oldDate = document.getElementById('startDate');
            var date_textnode = oldDate.firstChild;
            var date_text = date_textnode.data;
            myDateParts = date_text.split("-");

            var dd = myDateParts[2];

            var mm = myDateParts[1];

            var yy = myDateParts[0];

            selectCurrentWeek();

            window.location.href = "/timesheet?week_commencing=" + yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd; <<
```

At this point above this is where the window is refreshed and it GETs the URL. So that when I select a date it outputs like the following http://0.0.0.0:3000/timesheet?week_commencing=2011-09-05

```js
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });


    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });


});
```

**index.html.erb**

```js
window.onload = function getURL(){
    var url = document.location.href;
    urlSplit = url.split("/timesheet");

    if(urlSplit[1]== "")
    {
        var d = getMonday(new Date());

        dd = zeroPad(d.getDate(),2);
        mm = zeroPad(d.getMonth()+1,2);
        yy = d.getFullYear();

        document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
        //window.location.href = "/timesheet?week_commencing=" + yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    }
    else
    {
        week = url.split("week_commencing=");
        //return week[1];
        document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML = week[1];
    }
}
```

**Note**
The `window.onload` URL function gets the week commencing from the url

Jsfiddle - Including datepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/YQ2Zw/12/

Update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defaultDate` to set the initial date selected on the datepicker, and simulate a `click` event on the calendar to highlight the week:

```
var selectDate = '09/29/2011';

$('.week-picker').datepicker({
    defaultDate: selectDate
}).click(function(event) {
    // highlight the TR
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');

    // highlight the TD > A
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day:eq(0)").siblings().find('a').addClass('white');
}).click();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/15/

---

**Update**

Assuming Datepicker.js is loaded in `timesheet`, you should be able to do that with two more lines:

```
window.onload = function getURL(){
    var url = document.location.href;
    urlSplit = url.split("/timesheet");

    if(urlSplit[1]== "")
    {
        var d = getMonday(new Date());

        dd = zeroPad(d.getDate(),2);
        mm = zeroPad(d.getMonth()+1,2);
        yy = d.getFullYear();

        document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
        //window.location.href = "/timesheet?week_commencing=" + yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

        $('.week-picker').datepicker({
            defaultDate: mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy
        }).click();
    }
    else
    {
        week = url.split("week_commencing=");
        //return week[1];
        document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML = week[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked this out and it works, however.. When I select another week commencing example being 05/09/2011, once the page refreshes it will go back to the 29/09/2011, and this is because you declared a var selectDate. This is partially what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: the variable is there as an example, you get the date from the query string, as you stated in the question, `week_commencing=...`.

Comment: So should it look like the following: `$(function() {
    var selectDate = 'week_commencing=" + yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;';
    
    $('.week-picker').datepicker({
        defaultDate: selectDate,
    }).click(function(event) {
        // highlight the TR
        $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');

        // highlight the TD > A
        $(".ui-datepicker-current-day:eq(0)").siblings().find('a').addClass('white');
    }).click();
});`

Comment: Do you actually want the page to be refreshed upon user's date selection?

Comment: From the image you can see that it highlights fine when I select a date, however when the page is refreshed it no longer stays selected on that date. So in the image I selected the week commencing 12/09/2011, it should stay highlighted after the page is refreshed. But it is not doing that.

Comment: I know what you meant, but my question was more about your approach, as it is usually very interruptive for the user when you refresh a page. Anyhow, I updated the answer to do what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3086/discussion-between-user532339-and-william-niu)