# Date picker highlights after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery ui datepicker that highlights the week when i select a date. But because i am changing the URL location (to fit a parameter onto the end) the page refreshes and whatever i have clicked and highlighted is lost. I want to be able to click a date and when the page refreshes that week is highlighted. The week that needs to be highlighted can be taken from the URL so its just highlighting and highlighting after refresh that i need help with.

Heres the code:

```
$(function()
{
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var selectCurrentWeek = function()
    {
        window.setTimeout(function () { $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')}, 1);
    }
    function check(d) {
        if(d.length() == 2) {
            dd = d;
            return dd;
        } else {
            dd = "0" + myDateParts[0];
            return dd;
        }
    }

    var selectedWeek;//remember which week the user selected here

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd'
            var newDate = $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));

            var oldDate = document.getElementById('startDate');
            var date_textnode = oldDate.firstChild;
            var date_text = date_textnode.data;
            myDateParts = date_text.split("-");

            var dd = myDateParts[2];

            var mm = myDateParts[1];

            var yy = myDateParts[0];

            selectCurrentWeek();

            window.location.href = "/timesheet?week_commencing=" + yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });


    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });


});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Somehow I think you have asked the same question with a different ID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269582/how-to-get-datepicker-to-be-highlighted-upon-refresh/7271532

Comment: but i need it to work on refresh, that question doesnt... also thats not my question.

Comment: If you read the title carefully: "How to get datepicker to be highlighted upon **refresh**", yes, it _does_! If you `diff` the code, I believe you won't much output, i.e. they're virtually identical.

Comment: yeh i read the title... i tried your code... but it doesnt work. everytime it refreshes it resets. I even refactored your code so that it takes the date from the URL as the default date instead of a fixed date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concat the chosen weekNumber in the URL. Then when the page reloads extract the parameter from the URL and load the date picker accordingly.

Comment: var selectCurrentWeek = function()
    {
        window.setTimeout(function () { $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')}, 1);
    }

Comment: is that not what im doing now?

Comment: it is. but you're not calling it when the page loads with the chosenWeekNumber=43 extracted from the URL

Comment: you can use this method I wrote quickly, or you can use regex searching http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp
function getParameterFromURL(parameter){
 var URL = window.location.href;
 var startIndex = URL.indexOf(parameter) + parameter.length;
 var subString = URL.substring(startIndex);
 var endIndex = URL.indexOf("&")>-1 ? URL.indexOf("&") : URL.length ;
 return subString.substring(0,endIndex);
}

Comment: yep i see what your doing and my code above already does that. i just need to know what to do with variable afterwards and how id load the page with it